# JavaScript load a page on button click

Tags: javascript, button, load

I am trying to do a very simple task here, I would like to be able to click a button on a page and have it take me to another page. I have tried window.location.href, and a bunch of other things and it does nothing. I have tried different platforms and different browsers, all with the same result.

I know that it can call a function but I just cannot get the new page to load. Also this is all in my local file system and both pages live at the same level (but I have also tried to load an external page like www.apple.com).

Any thoughts?

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: You need to be more specific than "a bunch of other things."  Post your code (HTML and JavaScript) and tell us what errors you're getting.

Comment: Not a good idea: A button is experienced by the user as something that causes action/trigger (postback, save/load). A Link (a href) is jused for navigation. Do not mix those. You'll confuse users.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Simple code to redirect page

```
<!-- html button designing and calling the event in javascript -->
<input id="btntest" type="button" value="Check" 
       onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'" />
```

Comment: This one worked, however I think that my issue was that I had type="submit" and not type="button". Thanks for the help!

Comment: `window.location.assign()` worked better for me in firefox. For some reason assignment `=` messed history.

Answer (score 24):

Don't abuse form elements where <a> elements will suffice.

```
<style>
    /* or put this in your stylesheet */

    .button {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 3px 5px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background: #eee;
    }

</style>

<!-- instead of abusing a button or input element -->
<a href="url" class="button">text</a>
```

Comment: I was also thinking of going this way. Thank you for the help. I enjoy these buttons more anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried this button and it doesn't look good. It is just a link with a black line around it.

Answer (score 20):

Just `window.location = "http://wherever.you.wanna.go.com/"`, or, for local links, `window.location = "my_relative_link.html"`.

You can try it by typing it into your address bar as well, e.g. `javascript: window.location = "http://www.google.com/"`.

Also note that the protocol part of the URL (`http://`) is not optional for absolute links; omitting it will make javascript assume a relative link.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know you could run javascript in the browser, learn something new every day. I was trying the window.location and others like it but couldn't get it to work, and I knew that it should. I found that my "type" was wrong so it had nothing to do with the JavaScript and everything to do with the HTML. Thanks again for the advice.

Answer (score 5):

The answers here work to open the page in the same browser window/tab.

However, I wanted the page to open in a new window/tab when they click a button.
(tab/window decision depends on the user's browser setting)

So here is how it worked to **open the page in new tab/window**:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com/', '_blank');">View Example Page</button>
```

It doesn't have to be a button, you can use anywhere.
Notice the **_blank** that is used to open in new tab/window.