# i would like to reload the index.html page after clicking "ok" with alertify

Tags: javascript, html, alert, reload, alertify

I have this line of javascript in my code

```
alertify.alert("<div class='alert'>Some speech</div>");
```

I would like to reload the index.html page after clicking "ok"

Is it possible without going on alertify.confirm?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nyitsol/g2o52zq7/14/ Please show us what you tried already!

Comment: you can go through this [link1][1] or [link2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682805/javascript-load-a-page-on-button-click
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719729/i-want-to-load-another-html-page-after-a-specific-amount-of-time

Comment: What about this: http://jsfiddle.net/46xc9qny/1/ ?

Comment: without a callback function you wont see the dialog, i think the examples help him

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, You can use this code to achieve what you want:

```
alertify.alert("This is an alert dialog.", function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

Below is the link to the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5HygY/67/

I hope this helps.